# click link inside li tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

```
 <li id="tab1">
        <%= link_to_remote .... %>
 </li>
```

I am trying to click this link using prototype like

```
<% javascript_tag do %>

  $$('#tab1 a').click();

<% end %>



<% javascript_tag do %>

  $$('#tab1 a').simulate('click');

<% end %>
```

but everything failed.

Answer (score 1):

In Prototype there is no `Element.click` so that cannot work. There is an `Element.simulate` but it's non-standard, you have to add the [event.simulate.js library](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js) yourself.

`$$()` returns an array so you need to get an element either like `$$('#tab1 a')[0]` or more safely with [`invoke()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/).

```
$$('#tab1 a').invoke('simulate', 'click');
```